# How to separate 2 values from txt file with ajax click event

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a "like" and "dislike" button. Every click on like or dislike increments the value in the txt file:

```
<?php
$clickcount = explode("\n", file_get_contents('counter.txt'));
foreach($clickcount as $line){
  $tmp = explode('||', $line);
  $count[trim($tmp[0])] = trim($tmp[1]);
}

?>

<button id="like-btn" class="click-trigger" data-click-id="like">Like</button> 
<span id="like" class="click-count"><?php echo $count['like'];?></span> likes.

<button id="dislike-btn" class="click-trigger" data-click-id="dislike">Dislike</button> 
<span id="dislike" class="click-count"><?php echo $count['dislike'];?></span> dislikes.
```

The ajax:

```
$(document).on('click', '.click-trigger', function()
{
  var data = {'id':$(this).attr('data-click-id')};


  $.ajax({
  type : 'POST',
  url  : 'counter.php',
  data : data,
  success :  function(data)
           {                                                
                $(".click-count").fadeIn(500).show(function()
                {
                    $(".click-count").html(data);

                });                     
           }
  });
return false;
});
```

And the php:

```
<?php 

$file = 'counter.txt'; // path to text file that stores counts
$fh = fopen($file, 'r+');
$id = $_REQUEST['id']; // posted from page
$lines = '';
while(!feof($fh)){
$line = explode('||', fgets($fh));
$item = trim($line[0]);
$num = trim($line[1]);
if(!empty($item)){
    if($item == $id){
        $num++; // increment count by 1
        echo $num;

        }
    $lines .= "$item||$num\r\n";
    }
} 
file_put_contents($file, $lines);
fclose($fh);

?>
```

My problem is: when click on, lets say "like" button, after dislike is the same value as for likes. After age-refresh, there are different. So they should work separately from each other. How can I make this work fine?

By the way, the file`counter.txt` looks like this:

```
  like||41
  dislike||129
```

So this is what happens when click on "Like" button; dislike gets the value from like

```
Like 71 likes. 

Dislike 71 dislikes.
```

After page-refresh:

```
 Like 71 likes. 

Dislike 161 dislikes.
```

Comment: You should look into `json_encode` in php and return the response as json, rather than a format that your frontend will have to custom parse to get the information it is after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all... you should find a better way to store your data. Reading from a .txt like this is going to give you headaches and there may be data collision.

The problem is here...

```
$(".click-count").fadeIn(500).show(function()
{
    $(".click-count").html(data);
});
```

You are replacing ALL the elements that contain the "click-count" class, which is in both likes and dislikes.

Using [next](https://api.jquery.com/next/) should be enough.

```
$(document).on('click', '.click-trigger', function()
{
    var count = $(this).next(".click-count");
    [...]
}
```

And...

```
$(".click-count").fadeIn(500).show(function()
{
    count.html(data);
});
```

Comment: unfortunately, it gives me the same problem

Comment: he does not increment anymore now...Only after refresh

Comment: Didn't notice the elements are not inside the same parent. Use "next" instead of "closest".